# How to make a UIButton upresponsive

Tags: ios, uibutton

I have a case where I would like to make an already existing UIButton unresponsive and basically act as a UILabel.  Doesn't anyone know a way of doing this programmatically in c preferably?

Comment: You want UIbutton not to perform any action and blinking?

Answer (score 0):

Set it's .userInteractionEnabled property to false

Answer (score 0):

If you disable Interaction still you can see the UIButton blinking for click. Better you can **uncheck Enable button property from Accessibility.**

[image]:

This will help to achieve your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable userinteraction on your button something like,

```
  yourButton.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

And your button will not respond more!

Answer (score -1):

Disbale User Intercation by writing this code:

```
yourButton.userinteractionenabled=NO;
```